# React scroll to element after render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apollo, react-apollo

I am creating an app using React and Apollo Graphql. Part of my app consist of showing a list of options to the user so he can pick one. Once he picks one of them, the other options are hidden.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * Renders a list of simple products.
 */
export default function SimplesList(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Box>
      {props.childProducts
        .filter(child => showProduct(props.parentProduct, child))
        .map(child => (
          <SingleSimple
            key={child.id}
            product={child}
            menuItemCacheId={props.menuItemCacheId}
            parentCacheId={props.parentProduct.id}
          />
        ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

And the actual element:

```
export default function SingleSimple(props: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [ref, setRef] = useState(null);

  const [flipQuantity] = useFlipChosenProductQuantityMutation({
    variables: {
      input: {
        productCacheId: props.product.id,
        parentCacheId: props.parentCacheId,
        menuItemCacheId: props.menuItemCacheId,
      },
    },
    onError: err => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.error('Error executing Flip Chosen Product Quantity Mutation', err);
        Sentry.setExtras({ error: err, query: 'useFlipChosenProductQuantityMutation' });
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      }
    },
  });

  const [validateProduct] = useValidateProductMutation({
    variables: { productCacheId: props.menuItemCacheId },
    onError: err => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.error('Error executing Validate Product Mutation', err);
        Sentry.setExtras({ error: err, query: 'useValidateProductMutation' });
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      }
    },
  });

  const refCallback = useCallback(node => {
    setRef(node);
  }, []);

  const scrollToElement = useCallback(() => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
      });
    }
  }, [ref]);

  const onClickHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    await flipQuantity();
    if (props.product.isValid !== ProductValidationStatus.Unknown) {
      validateProduct();
    }

    scrollToElement();
  }, [flipQuantity, props.product.isValid, validateProduct, scrollToElement]);

  return (
    <ListItem className={classes.root}>
      <div ref={refCallback}>
        <Box display='flex' alignItems='center' onClick={onClickHandler}>
          <Radio
            edge='start'
            checked={props.product.chosenQuantity > 0}
            tabIndex={-1}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': props.product.name! }}
            color='primary'
            size='medium'
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.text}
            primary={props.product.name}
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2' }}
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.price}
            primary={getProductPrice(props.product)}
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2', noWrap: true, align: 'right' }}
          />
        </Box>
        {props.product.chosenQuantity > 0 &&
          props.product.subproducts &&
          props.product.subproducts.map(subproduct => (
            <ListItem component='div' className={classes.multiLevelChoosable} key={subproduct!.id}>
              <Choosable
                product={subproduct!}
                parentCacheId={props.product.id}
                menuItemCacheId={props.menuItemCacheId}
                is2ndLevel={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
      </div>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

My problem is this: once the user selects an element from the list, I would like to scroll the window to that element, because he will have several lists to choose from and he can get lost when choosing them. However my components are using this flow:

1- The user clicks on a given simple element.

2- This click fires an async mutation that chooses this element over the others.

3- The application state is updated and all components from the list are re-created (the ones that were not selected are filtered out and the one that was selected is displayed).

4- On the re-creation is done, I would like to scroll to the selected component.

The thing is that when the `flipQuantity` quantity mutation finishes its execution, I call the `scrollToElement` callback, but the ref it contains is for the unselected element, that is no longer rendered on the screen, since the new one will be recreated by the `SimplesList` component.

How can I fire the `scrollIntoView` function on the most up-to-date component?

**UPDATE:**

Same code, but with the `useRef` hook:

```
export default function SingleSimple(props: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const [flipQuantity] = useFlipChosenProductQuantityMutation({
    variables: {
      input: {
        productCacheId: props.product.id,
        parentCacheId: props.parentCacheId,
        menuItemCacheId: props.menuItemCacheId,
      },
    },
    onError: err => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.error('Error executing Flip Chosen Product Quantity Mutation', err);
        Sentry.setExtras({ error: err, query: 'useFlipChosenProductQuantityMutation' });
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      }
    },
  });

  const [validateProduct] = useValidateProductMutation({
    variables: { productCacheId: props.menuItemCacheId },
    onError: err => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.error('Error executing Validate Product Mutation', err);
        Sentry.setExtras({ error: err, query: 'useValidateProductMutation' });
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      }
    },
  });

  const scrollToElement = useCallback(() => {
    if (ref && ref.current) {
      ref.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
      });
    }
  }, [ref]);

  const onClickHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    await flipQuantity();
    if (props.product.isValid !== ProductValidationStatus.Unknown) {
      validateProduct();
    }

    scrollToElement();
  }, [flipQuantity, props.product.isValid, validateProduct, scrollToElement]);

  return (
    <ListItem className={classes.root}>
      <div ref={ref}>
        <Box display='flex' alignItems='center' onClick={onClickHandler}>
          <Radio
            edge='start'
            checked={props.product.chosenQuantity > 0}
            tabIndex={-1}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': props.product.name! }}
            color='primary'
            size='medium'
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.text}
            primary={props.product.name}
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2' }}
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.price}
            primary={getProductPrice(props.product)}
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2', noWrap: true, align: 'right' }}
          />
        </Box>
        {props.product.chosenQuantity > 0 &&
          props.product.subproducts &&
          props.product.subproducts.map(subproduct => (
            <ListItem component='div' className={classes.multiLevelChoosable} key={subproduct!.id}>
              <Choosable
                product={subproduct!}
                parentCacheId={props.product.id}
                menuItemCacheId={props.menuItemCacheId}
                is2ndLevel={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
      </div>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I changed my component once again as per Kornflexx suggestion, but it is still not working:

```
export default function SingleSimple(props: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const ref = useRef(null);

  const [needScroll, setNeedScroll] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (needScroll) {
      scrollToElement();
    }
  }, [ref]);

  const [flipQuantity] = useFlipChosenProductQuantityMutation({
    variables: {
      input: {
        productCacheId: props.product.id,
        parentCacheId: props.parentCacheId,
        menuItemCacheId: props.menuItemCacheId,
      },
    },
    onError: err => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.error('Error executing Flip Chosen Product Quantity Mutation', err);
        Sentry.setExtras({ error: err, query: 'useFlipChosenProductQuantityMutation' });
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      }
    },
  });

  const [validateProduct] = useValidateProductMutation({
    variables: { productCacheId: props.menuItemCacheId },
    onError: err => {
      if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
        console.error('Error executing Validate Product Mutation', err);
        Sentry.setExtras({ error: err, query: 'useValidateProductMutation' });
        Sentry.captureException(err);
      }
    },
  });

  const scrollToElement = useCallback(() => {
    if (ref && ref.current) {
      ref.current.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        block: 'start',
      });
    }
  }, [ref]);

  const onClickHandler = useCallback(async () => {
    await flipQuantity();
    if (props.product.isValid !== ProductValidationStatus.Unknown) {
      validateProduct();
    }

    setNeedScroll(true);
  }, [flipQuantity, props.product.isValid, validateProduct, scrollToElement]);

  return (
    <ListItem className={classes.root}>
      <div ref={ref}>
        <Box display='flex' alignItems='center' onClick={onClickHandler}>
          <Radio
            edge='start'
            checked={props.product.chosenQuantity > 0}
            tabIndex={-1}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-labelledby': props.product.name! }}
            color='primary'
            size='medium'
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.text}
            primary={props.product.name}
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2' }}
          />
          <ListItemText
            className={classes.price}
            primary={getProductPrice(props.product)}
            primaryTypographyProps={{ variant: 'body2', noWrap: true, align: 'right' }}
          />
        </Box>
        {props.product.chosenQuantity > 0 &&
          props.product.subproducts &&
          props.product.subproducts.map(subproduct => (
            <ListItem component='div' className={classes.multiLevelChoosable} key={subproduct!.id}>
              <Choosable
                product={subproduct!}
                parentCacheId={props.product.id}
                menuItemCacheId={props.menuItemCacheId}
                is2ndLevel={true}
              />
            </ListItem>
          ))}
      </div>
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

Now I am getting this error:

```
index.js:1375 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
```

Comment: Can you use useRef (as the correct hooks for working with element ref), then update your code sample ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the `useRef` hook, but the results were the same. In this case, I don't know how to trigger the `scrollIntoView` after the component is selected.

Comment: You can use `const [scrollNeeded, setScrollNeeded] = useState(false)`. Replace `scrollToElement()` by `setScrollNeeded(true)`. Add an effect that, when ref change, check if `scrollNeeded` is true, set `scrollNeeded` to false and call `scrollToElement`

Comment: I also tried that, but it didn't work. The problem is that the `SingleSimple` component is always recreated by the `SimplesList`, so when my state changes, the `SingleSimple` component is recreated and this new component's `scrollNeed` will always be `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've previously solved this by adding a local state flag to items that should be scrolled to when they appear:

```
apolloClient.mutate({
  mutation: MY_MUTATE,
  variables: { ... },
  update: (proxy, { data: { result } }) => {
    // We mark the item with the local prop `addedByThisSession` so that we know to
    // scroll to it once mounted in the DOM.
    apolloClient.cache.writeData({ id: `MyType:${result._id}`, data: { ... result, addedByThisSession: true } });
  }
})
```

Then when it mounts, I force the scroll and clear the flag:

```
import scrollIntoView from 'scroll-into-view-if-needed';

...

const GET_ITEM = gql`
  query item($id: ID!) {
    item(_id: $id) {
      ...
      addedByThisSession @client
    }
  }
`;

...

const MyItem = (item) => {
  const apolloClient = useApolloClient();
  const itemEl = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Scroll this item into view if it's just been added in this session
    // (i.e. not on another browser or tab)
    if (item.addedByThisSession) {
      scrollIntoView(itemEl.current, {
        scrollMode: 'if-needed',
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });

      // Clear the addedByThisSession flag
      apolloClient.cache.writeFragment({
        id: apolloClient.cache.config.dataIdFromObject(item),
        fragment: gql`
          fragment addedByThisSession on MyType {
            addedByThisSession
          }
        `,
        data: {
          __typename: card.__typename,
          addedByThisSession: false,
        },
      });
    }
  });

  ...
```

Doing it this way means that I can completely separate the mutation from the item's rendering, and I can by sure that the scroll will only occur once the item exists in the DOM.